# Having trouble plotting this data frame of mutual funds

Tags: python, pandas, plot, cluster-analysis

First off, here is my dataframe:

```
Date    2012-09-04 00:00:00 2012-09-05 00:00:00 2012-09-06 00:00:00 2012-09-07 00:00:00 2012-09-10 00:00:00 2012-09-11 00:00:00 2012-09-12 00:00:00 2012-09-13 00:00:00 2012-09-14 00:00:00 2012-09-17 00:00:00 ... 2017-08-22 00:00:00 2017-08-23 00:00:00 2017-08-24 00:00:00 2017-08-25 00:00:00 2017-08-28 00:00:00 2017-08-29 00:00:00 2017-08-30 00:00:00 2017-08-31 00:00:00 2017-09-01 00:00:00 Type
AABTX   9.73    9.73    9.83    9.86    9.83    9.86    9.86    9.96    9.98    9.96    ... 11.44   11.45   11.44   11.46   11.46   11.47   11.47   11.51   11.52   Hybrid
AACTX   9.66    9.65    9.77    9.81    9.78    9.81    9.82    9.92    9.95    9.93    ... 12.32   12.32   12.31   12.33   12.34   12.34   12.35   12.40   12.41   Hybrid
AADTX   9.71    9.70    9.85    9.90    9.86    9.89    9.91    10.02   10.07   10.05   ... 13.05   13.04   13.03   13.05   13.06   13.06   13.08   13.14   13.15   Hybrid
AAETX   9.92    9.91    10.07   10.13   10.08   10.12   10.14   10.26   10.32   10.29   ... 13.84   13.84   13.82   13.85   13.86   13.86   13.89   13.96   13.98   Hybrid
AAFTX   9.85    9.84    10.01   10.06   10.01   10.05   10.07   10.20   10.26   10.23   ... 14.09   14.08   14.07   14.09   14.11   14.11   14.15   14.24   14.26   Hybrid
```

That is a bit hard to read but essentially these are just closing prices for several mutual funds (638) which the `Type` label in the last column. I'd like to plot all of these on a single plot and have a legend labeling what type each plot is.

I'd like to see how many potential clusters I may need. This was my first though to visualize the data but if you have any other recommendations, feel free to suggest it.

Also, in my first attempt, I tried:

```
parallel_coordinates(closing_data, 'Type', alpha=0.2, colormap=dark2_cmap)
plt.show()
```

It just shows up as a black blob and after some research I found that it doesn't handle large number of features that well.

Comment: it's better to post the related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to transpose the dataframe, as timestamp comes more naturally as an index and you will be able to address individual time series as `df.AABTX` or `df['AABTX']`.

With a smaller number of time series you could have tried df.plot(), but when in it is rather large you should not be surpried to see some mess initially.

Try plotting a subset of your data, but please make sure the time is in index, not columns names.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like the [silhouette analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html) which is implemented in the scikit-learn machine learning library. It should allow to find an optimal number of clusters to consider for your data.